# FB.Connect is undefined

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to use `FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect` but I get this error:

> FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect [Break On
>   This Error]
>   FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect("/logout");

I've inserted this code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>  
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>    FB.init({
     appId  : 'my app id',
     status : true, // check login status
     cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the
session
     xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML    });  
</script>
```

after `<body>` tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FB.Connect` is based on the legacy JS SDK, and you're using the [new FB JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). To get the functionality you're after, try [`FB.logout`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/):

```
function fbLogout()
{
    FB.logout(function()
    {
        top.location.href = 'whatever';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will always work:

```
function fBlogout(){
    try{
        FB.Connect.ifUserConnected(function(){
            FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect('http://fullurl.com/account/logout');
        }, 'http://fullurl.com/account/logout');
    }catch(e){
        location.href = 'http://fullurl.com/account/logout';
    }
}

HTML Link:
<a href="#" onclick="FBlogout(); return false;">Log Out</a>
```

Reference: [FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect(''account/logout') will not redirect, even with proper session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308411/fb-connect-logoutandredirectaccount-logout-will-not-redirect-even-with-prop)

Comment: Yes, this function looks good, but FB.Connect is still undefined :(

Comment: Your code works for me when I add the proper indention. Try putting a new line before });</script>

Comment: `FB.Connect` is the legacy SDK; the new one is just `FB.`, so this won't work as long as he's referencing the new SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Your script tag is incorrect:

```
<script> src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
      ^^^
```

with that extra `>`, you've made the `src=...` part be the actual javascript, just defines a variable named 'src'. so you're not actually including the FB javascript.