# How can I delete cookies for specific website using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is there a way to get cookies for specific domain (Facebook) and delete all them using JavaScript?

I want to delete cookies for oAuth (Facebook and Gmail) when the user logs out.

Comment: Is this for a browser extension, or to be run in a webpage? You can't do this if you're running it from a webpage; it's horribily insecure and wide open to abuse.

Comment: i have done login using oAuth, i need to delete cookies of facebook from my application

Comment: Yes, you said that in your original question. Regurgitating what you've already posted doesn't further my understanding of your problem.

Comment: If you could use cookies from `facebook.com`, you could probably steal your visitor's Facebook account. I think you haven't explained your need but the solution you've figured out. I suggest you explain what you want to accomplish; it's possible that it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

You can only access the cookies of your own domain. You can't even see the cookies from a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)  is useful for getting the value of a cookie when you already know the name of the cookie you want to query, but provides no way to get a list of all the cookies that are set.

Refer this [DOC](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-get-all-cookies/) for details !!!!

For deleting cookies you can use  eraseCookie function

Comment: I could be wrong, but as far as I know, JavaScript is only able to access cookies for the domain it's been downloaded from.

Comment: @JamWaffles :if you wanna delete use eraseCookie

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand this correctly you actually want to logout the user from FB... Have you tried using the [FB SDK logout()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) function? That will successfully delete all FB cookies from your domain.

Hope this helps

Comment: FB.logout(function (response) {
                alert('user is now logged out');}

Comment: yes, that's a known issue with FB - [check this for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308411/fb-connect-logoutandredirectaccount-logout-will-not-redirect-even-with-pro) or some [client code](http://s433.codeinspot.com/q/1483892)